# Reuse Fragment with nested fragments after replace transaction

Tags: java, android

I have `mainFrag` that have 2 tabs (without `ViewPager`) and container layout that show 2 fragment `frag1` and `frag2`.

The app is using **replace** transactions, `mainFrag` also added to `backstack`, `mainFrag` using `childFragmentManager` to replace fragments.

The problem the `frag1` and `frag2` **not** using `backstack` and recreated every time - `onCreate` is called, and loading data from REST request

How possible to solve this issue without overhead and maybe some good practice in this cases(using single `Activity`)?

[image]

Comment: Do you want `onBackPressed()` to go back from `frag2` to `frag1`? Or does pressing back not affect those Fragments at all?

Comment: back pressing not effect on 'frag2' and 'frag1'. when 'mainFrag' replaced with some other fragment and when user return to 'mainFrag' onBackPress i want not to load the nested fragments again

Comment: Is it onCreate() that gets called after you press on back button, or onCreateView()?

Comment: on back press `mainFrag` recreated from `onCreateView()` that is fine, nested fragments `frag1` and `frag2` called from `onCreate()`

Comment: Slightly odd question here, but what was the reason for not using the View Pager powered tabs?

Comment: @binaryKarmic the reason is because my recycle's view item uses swipe options, and it can conflict with by view pager

Comment: Your question is absolutely valid and I don`t want to sideline it. But with context to viewpagers you can always turn off the swipe interaction. Only tabs will listen to clicks and change the page.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot restore fragment state after `replace`.
From [Official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace):

> `FragmentTransaction replace (int containerViewId, Fragment fragment, String tag)`
>
> Replace an existing fragment that was added to a container. This is essentially the same as calling `remove(Fragment)` for all currently added fragments that were added with the same containerViewId and then `add(int, Fragment, String)` with the same arguments given here.

You can try `hide(Fragment)`, `show(Fragment)` if you want to kepp fragment state.

**EDIT**

if you want to navigate on them via `onBackPressed()`, you should create your own backstack array

**For Example:**

First Fragment:

```
class Fragment1 : Fragment() {
        override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1_view, container, false)
        }

        companion object {
            fun newInstance() = Fragment1()
        }
    }
```

Second Fragment:

```
class Fragment2 : Fragment() {
        override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2_view, container, false)
        }

        companion object {
            fun newInstance() = Fragment2()
        }
    }
```

Activity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val backStack = mutableListOf<String>()
    private val fragment1:Fragment1 = Fragment1.newInstance()
    private val fragment2:Fragment2 = Fragment2.newInstance()
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container, fragment1, "Fragment1")
            .add(R.id.container, fragment2, "Fragment2")
            .commit()
        backStack.add("Fragment1")
        backStack.add("Fragment2")
    }
    
    fun showFragment1() {
        if (backStack.last() == "Fragment1") return
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .hide(fragment2)
            .show(fragment1)
            .commit()
        backStack.add("Fragment1")
    }

    fun showFragment2() {
        if (backStack.last() == "Fragment2") return
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .hide(fragment1)
            .show(fragment2)
            .commit()
        backStack.add("Fragment1")
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        if (backStack.size < 2) super.onBackPressed()
        val last = backStack.removeAt(backStack.size - 1)
        if (last == "Fragment1") {
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .hide(fragment1)
                .show(fragment2)
                .commit()
        } else {
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .hide(fragment2)
                .show(fragment1)
                .commit()
        }
    }

}
```

[More](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html#hide) about `hide()`

[More](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html#show) about `show()`

Comment: I wounder how much hide/show will be, and probably need to handle all this in onBackPressed()

Comment: Man below @ianhanniballake do it right with ```replace```

Answer (score 2):

As per [the Fragments documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments#Transactions), you should be using `addToBackStack()` along with your `replace()` operation to add your Fragment B to the back stack:

```
// Create new fragment and transaction
Fragment newFragment = new ExampleFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

// Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
// and add the transaction to the back stack
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);

// Commit the transaction
transaction.commit();
```

When you do this, FragmentManager takes care of handling `onBackPressed()` for you, reversing the `replace()` operation and restoring the previous Fragment, restoring its saved instance state, view state, etc.

Comment: Not sure how it restores the view state, onCreateView called again and triggers some REST requests, getView() is null so i cannot return the old view, i used this code already but it recreate the fragment and fetch data, now the requirements was changed and need to skip to loading new data on backpress, not understand what i am missing

Comment: Views have their own saved instance state, which is saved before `onDestroyView()` is called and the old View instances destroyed and is restored as part of `onViewStateRestored()` after your `onCreateView()` creates new instances. If you want to only do your request once, you should be doing it in `onCreate()` (which is only called once) or in a [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) (which would have the additional benefit of having your data survive configuration changes).

Comment: I have updated my question, maybe its more clear now